# playing demuxed audio/video packet using GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I am newbie in multimedia. I have a application where I am getting demuxed audio/video packet. I checked GStreamer tutorials but most of the examples are based on url muxed stream.
Does GStreamer provides such interface where one can pass demux audio/video buffer for video playback?

Comment: Please clarify. How is it already demuxed, are you reading from two streams?

Comment: maybe appsrc? and continue pipeline from that.. maybe you will have to play with signalising to the gstreamer the format of frames etc.. I think  appsrc has functions for that ..

Comment: Thanks otopolsky, appsrc seem to be the required interface which can solve my problem.

Comment: @diehard I added answer, if it is really what you wanted you can accept it, also added some useful links.. also in some version of gstreamer I found out that the appsrc was little buggy (it frozen the pipe at some special condition)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appsrc is capable pushing data from your application into gstreamer pipeline.

The pipeline can be:

your demuxed data -> appsrc ! some-decoder ! some-sink

[Here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-data-spoof.html) is some example and info about appsrc.

Also you can check some more examples [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/tests/examples/app)